# How to save the ID of a saved file using GridFS?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, gridfs

I am trying to save the ID of the file that I send via GridFS to my MongoDB (working with Mongoose). However I cant seem to find out how to get the created ID in fs.files with code?

```
var writestream = gfs.createWriteStream({
    filename: req.file.originalname
});

fs.createReadStream(req.file.path).pipe(writestream);

writestream.on('close', function (file) {
    // do something with `file`
    console.log(file.filename + 'Written To DB');
});
```

I cant seem to be able to save the ID of the File that I wrote via the writestream.

The file is created in the lists etc. but how do I manage to save the file so that I can save it in one of my other MongoDB Documents?

Comment: Log the file object.  It should be file._id

Answer (score 1):

This is old and I think you already solved you problem.
If I correctly understood, you were trying to get the id of the saved file.
You can simply do this:

```
console.log(writestream.id);
```

Comment: Good answers never considered late. Thanks for this, it worked.